# Howto detect clicked object on bootstrap popover open?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I used this code:

```
    var options = {
        title: 'title <button type="button" id="closepopover" onclick="closePopover(obj);">&times;</button>',
        html: true,
    };
    $('a').popover(options);
```

I want get clicked  object (parameter: obj) on close popover to pass to this function:

```
function closePopover(obj) {
   obj.popover('hide');
}
```

thanks

Comment: you can write $(document).on("click","#closepopover",function(){});

Comment: I want find obj for `popover('hide');`

Answer (score 0):

solution is this code in closing button:

```
    var obj = $(this).parents('.popover.in').prev();
    obj.popover('hide');
```